# Hide Chat Without losing the messages it is rendering in UseEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, socket.io

I am making a chat app. In which I am giving a toggle button if the user want to see the chat or not. Chat is working totally fine. But the toggle button perform show and hide option of that component. Problem I am facing is when I hide the Chat component and toggle it again. I loose all the previous chat in it and the messages continue to sended by the other users.

I want to keep the chat component running in back for new message . How can I achieve this

```
{
 (!chatToggle) ? <Chat location={location} /> : null
}
```

Chat.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import io from "socket.io-client";

//components 
import InfoBar from './RoomInfoBar/InfoBar'
import TypeMessage from './TypeMessage/TypeMessage'
import Messages from "./Messages/Messages";
import { useParams } from "react-router";



let socket;


function Chat({ location }) {
    
    const ENDPOINT = 'http://localhost:5000/';

    const [name, setName] = useState('');
    const [room, setRoom] = useState('');
    const [users, setUsers] = useState('');
    const [message, setMessage] = useState('');
    const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

    // when using params 
    const { userName, roomId } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {

        // const { name, room } = queryString.parse(location.search);
        socket = io.connect(ENDPOINT);
        setRoom(roomId);
        setName(userName);

        socket.emit('join-room', { name : userName, room : roomId }, (error) => {
            if (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        })

        return (() => {
            console.log('I am lea')
            socket.emit('leave');
            socket.off();
        })
    }, [ENDPOINT, location.search]);
    console.log(messages)


    useEffect(() => {
        socket.on('message', message => {
            setMessages(messages => [...messages, message]);
        });

        socket.on("roomData", ({ users }) => {
            setUsers(users);
        });
    }, []);

    const sendMessage = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (message) {
            socket.emit('sendMessage', message, () => setMessage(''));
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <InfoBar room={room} />
            <Messages messages={messages} name={name} />
            <TypeMessage message={message} setMessage={setMessage} sendMessage={sendMessage} />
        </>
    )
}

export default Chat
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep it loaded, don't make it null. This will cause it be removed completely. Instead, just wrap this chat component inside a div and toggle it's visibility using css.

Update your code as:

```
<div className={!chatToggle ? "" : "hidden"}>
    <Chat location={location} />
</div>
```

and create a CSS class like:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```